# Como programar lo siguiente en R

Tags: r

estoy iniciandome en R y no se como podría programar lo siguiente.
Teniendo el siguiente Data Frame:

```
df <- data.frame(Nombre = c("Pepe","Juan","Maria","Antonia"),
                 Edad = c(15, 35, 25, 41),
                 Ciudad = c("Barcelona","Castello","Girona","Alacant"))
```

1- Necesito sacar las personas que tienen más de 27 años
2- Necesito calcular la media de edad de las personas que son de Castelló y Alacant, sobre este data.frame u otro data.frame con la misma estructura y diferentes registros.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Son dos cosas muy básicas y simples de hacer en R:

Las selección de filas según la edad:

```
df[df$Edad > 27,]
```

Nos sirve que `df$Edad > 27` termina siendo un vector de lógicos, que podemos usar para seleccionar las filas.

La media de edad de ciertas ciudades, es algo parecido, solo que usamos la función `%in%` para comparar un valor en un conjunto.

```
mean(df$Edad[df$Ciudad %in% c("Castello","Alacant")])
```